# API que se comunica com banco de dados utilizando Django

Tags: python, api, django, django-rest-framework

A API precisa ser feita em Django, e no banco de dados só precisa de duas tabelas.

Em uma tabela irá ter uma coluna com nomes, e na segunda tabela uma coluna irá ter objetos e outra uma foreign key que se associa ao nome da primeira tabela.

Qual modelo devo usar para essa foreign key?

```py
    from django.db import models
    
    # Create your models here.
    
    
    class Fruits(models.Model):
        fruits = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        id_region = models.ForeignKey()
    
    class Region(models.Model):
        region = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Answer (score 0):

Se a model Region é a principal de seu banco de dados, quem recebera a foreignKey será a fruits. Exemplo:

```
class Region(models.Model):
    region = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Fruits(models.Model):
    fruits = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    id_region = models.ForeignKey(Region, related_name="fruits", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Dessa forma você consegue acessar a região e saber qual a fruta da mesma, basta fazer um simples nested no serializer, exemplo:

```
class Fruists_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Fruits
        fields = {'id',
                  'fruits',
                  'id_region'
                  }

class Region(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fruits = Fruists_Serializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Region
        fields = {
            'id',
            'region'
            'fruits'
        }
```

Na serialização da região, invocamos o serializer de fruits e pedimos a tabela de fruits quais são as frutas que estão sendo vinculada aquela região. É um pouco complexo de entender a lógica, mas o que fizemos foi: pegamos todas as frutas que estão vinculadas aquela região, logo depois serializamos ela e enviamos para o serializer da Region.

Você consegue ver todos os métodos da ForeingKey no site do próprio django: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

Answer (score 0):

A [Documentação Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) explica bem a utilização do ForeingKey, e [aqui traz um exemplo](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) de relacionamentos Many-to-one (que acredito se encaixar melhor nos seus modelos):

```
class Fruits(models.Model):
        fruits = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        id_region = models.ForeignKey('Region', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Region(models.Model):
        region = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Um relacionamento "Many-to-one" requer dois argumentos: a classe para qual o modelo está relacionada e a opção "on delete".

Quando a classe a ser relacionada ainda não foi declarada, pode ser utilizada o nome da classe como uma string (como o exemplo mostrado na pergunta).

**Opções on_delete:**

- CASCADE: ao deletar Region deletará também as Fruits relacionadas
- PROTECT: retorna um ProtectedError ao tentar deletar uma região que possui Fruits  relacionadas
- RESTRICT: evita deleção e retorna um RestrictedError, porém, diferentemente do PROTECT, permite a deleção quando esta referencia a deleção de outro objeto com a opção CASCADE na mesma operação.

PS.: Não realizei nenhum teste, a resposta foi escrita com base na documentação já referenciada.

Comment: ajudou bastante, muito obrigado!!